# Naming scheme for compute nodes in a slurm cluster?

Tags: slurm

I am planning to build a new computer cluster based on Debian 11, Slurm, and a diverse range of hardware. The cluster will boot from a network location using PXE. It is expected that the cluster will expand over time, so I would like to have the flexibility to easily add any number of new nodes.

However, I am not very experienced with slurm; my insight on reaches as far as being able to configure the nodes in a config file - is there a better (=more dynamic) way? Also, since the nodes are 'diskless', they won't necessarily be born with a hostname, and they will acquire an IP address from DHCP, which makes it harder to configure the cluster in advance. I imagine there must be ways to manage this?

I have tried to search for this both here and in google, but it doesn't seem to be a subject that has received much attention since the early 2000s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would configure the DHCP server to assign hostnames and probably IP addresses to each server in the cluster. This is easily done using the server'sMAC address.

You have a few options for hostname templates. Since Slurm supports using numeric ranges in the config files and commands, using names like `node001`, `node002`, etc. will make life easier and will allow up to 999 nodes. This allows commands like `sinfo -n node[001-010]`. Note that you cannot have any characters after the numeric part of the hostname.

If your site has a different naming convention you can put aliases into the slurm configuration file.

```
NodeName=node001 NodeHostName=org-slurm-001
```

Comment: Makes sense - but how can IO update the slurm configuration dynamically? Like, if I have N nodes and then add some more, is there a way to automatically add the new nodes (that is, without manual steps)?

Comment: You could probably write a script to check what nodes are reachable in the list `node[001-999]` and modify `/etc/slurm/slurm.conf` with the returned list. Since I am not adding or removing nodes on a daily or weekly basis I have not gone that route and I would not trust it on a production cluster. Or you could just add all 999 nodes into the slurm configuration and have the majority of them listed as down.